# C# CommunityToolkit.Mvvm ObservableProperty on a list

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I want to try the [Community Toolkit 8.0](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-the-dotnet-community-toolkit-800/) the MVVM part.

I have a very simple application:

```xml
.... 
       d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type=local:MainWindowViewModel}"
.... 
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="12*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Button x:Name="ButtonDirectory" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Margin="50 2 0 2" Width="200" Content="List Directory" Command="{Binding ClickButtonListDirectoryCommand, Mode=OneWay}" />
        <ListView x:Name="ListViewDirectories" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" ItemsSource="{Binding DirectoriesNames}"  />
    </Grid>
```

and this is my viewmodel:

```cs
public partial class MainWindowViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    [ObservableProperty]
    List<string> _directoriesNames = new();

    [RelayCommand]
    private void ClickButtonListDirectory()
    {
        this.DirectoriesNames.Add("Hello");
    }
}
```

This construct works, when I use `string` instead of a list - but obviously I want to use something like a list when my view component is a ListView.

The `directoriesNames` itself gets updated (saw that in the debugger) but it's not displayed in the view (`ListView`).

Can someone help me out with that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Change your `List` to `ObservableCollection`.

This code:

```cs
[ObservableProperty]
List<string> _directoriesNames = new();
```

Will notify the UI when the **DirectoriesNames** itself is changed but the only change you are making to **DirectoriesNames** is instantiating it.

You can use a **ObservableCollection** to notify the UI when you **add** or **remove** items.

Comment: Yeps, that's it. Thank you very much for the additional explanation why List will not work :-)

Answer (score 4):

You need to use [ObservableCollection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.objectmodel.observablecollection-1?view=net-6.0) :-

`ObservableCollection<string> DirectoriesNames = new();`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).